# Create a child contract from parent contract via remix

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I was trying to create a new contract from another one like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Child {
    address public owner;

    function Child() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}

contract Parent {
    address owner;

    event NewChildCreated(address childAddress, address creator);

    function Parent() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function createChild() public {
        Child child = new Child();
        NewChildCreated(address(child), child.owner());
    }
}
```

So in remix I called `createChild()` from the `Parent` and there is a log with the address of that newly-created `Child` contract (e.g. `0x1234`).

However, when I copied that address and created a `Child` instance based on that address (`0x1234`) in remix, I was not able to access the `owner` property of it. I was getting this error: `call to Child.owner errored: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Am I creating the child contract wrongly? Why I cannot refer to the newly-created Child contract?

Comment: Strange. I can reproduce the error when using the JavaScript VM but not when using `ganache`.